# How to flag recipients for follow up

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

[image]

Dears, I need help to amend the below vba code that I'm using to send emails with follow up flag with a reminder.

Need to amend the code to flag follow up for all recipients / all receivers of this email with a reminder as shown in the picture as this code flags the sender only not recipients.
Simply: when i press on the button (macro) it flags follow up for me only.
Can any one amend the code to flag me and the recipient ?

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With EmailItem
.To= Range("L4")
.CC= "someone@somewhere.com" &";"&"someone2@somewhere.com"
. Subject=""
.Body =""

.FlagStatus = olFlagMarked
.FlagRequest = "Follow up"
.ReminderTime = Range("I1").value & " 10:30 AM"
.ReminderSet = True
.ReminderOverrideDefault = True

.send
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Need to amend the code to flag follow up for all recipients` So where are you stuck?. I think you may have misunderstood how stackoverflow operates. You may want to see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please post what you have tried so far. Keep these in mind while posting **1.** What were you expecting? **2.** What is not working? Include Error message if applicable and we will take it from there :)

Comment: Need to amend the code to flag for all recipients as the code flag follow up for the sender only(who press at the button)(flag for me)

Comment: Re-tag your question. It has nothing to do with visio nor excel.

Comment: If this worked in earlier versions of Outlook, it may have been a bug. Appears there is no mailitem property to specify the recipient. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem. Given you think setting a followup would be acceptable to the recipient you are probably in a position to assign a task. Due date may be a reasonable alternative. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.taskitem.assign

Comment: It is very clear and good idea. Due date can be assigned to Range ? Right?

Comment: It looks like `.DueDate = Range("I1").value & " 10:30 AM"` should be good. Try it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `MailItem.FlagRequest` property.

Comment: please can you describe it in more details. How can I use MailItem.FlagRequest property in this code, if you can rewrite it will be appreciated

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: @BasemZaki You already have `EmailItem.FlagRequest`.