# How do I merge rows individually that are between borders using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task that I'd like to automate for an excel file I have which is very big. I can't seem to find some proper examples as i never worked with VBA. I need to do something like this [image]For each row i need to do this for whatever text is between the thick border.
Sorry if i am not clear enough.

Comment: Are there all the time two rows and only one column in the borders delimited area? Are there intermediary rows not bordered? I mean, is it possible to have some rows as we can see in your pictures, followed by some other rows without borders and again bordered rows to be processed in the way you try explaining?

Comment: Sorry if I will not properly answer to your question but let me give it a try. There can be 1 to 4 rows between the borders delimited area and no, from what i saw every raw is bordered like in the image above( with 2 or more/less rows).
For the columns, i can pretty much delete the empty one and leave on the ones with text on them if this makes the coding harder. I was initially thinking that maybe i can do a vba code to take just the border into considerations for each row. Eg: rows with QD it see that it's between borders and merges them,same for QS and so on, moves to the next row with S

Comment: So, concluding variable rows and one column inside the bordered range, you must also confirm that all the cells on the bordered area rows will be concatenated on top of the area cells (first area row). Should this understanding be a correct one? I mean for a bordered area containing four rows, there should be three concatenations... Existing row plus the following three. Since you did not say anything about any gaps between the bordered areas, should I also understand that such cases do not occur?

Comment: I will attach a link to imgur because i don't know how to add pictures in another way and i hope it will me more explicit : https://imgur.com/a/7Y7d1UG .The only columns I am interested in are the ones with the languages : French, English, Bulgarian etc, there are many translations. Like we have cells C3, C4 and C5, i need to merge/concatenate them into one cell , same goes for the entire row (G2, G3 and G4) than after this is done it move to the next bordered area C7 and C8 and merges them together goes to the column and so on and yes like you said, if 4 rows are bordered there are 4 concat

Comment: If at the beginning I was confused, I must confess now that I do not understand anything. You firstly must learn how to ask a question... I am able to determine the range between two thick borders, but looking to your picture which should clarify something, I am not able to understand what you want. The mentioned range of column G:G **does not end in a thick border line**. Are there some other columns, not visible in the picture, with these three languages?

Comment: And what about gaps between such bordered ranges?

Comment: It is true that some of the columns do not end with thick borders but i can add them manually to make the final code easier, it shouldn't be a problem there. This is fairly complex to me so this is why i have trouble explaining, i am sorry. The columns are with translations in each Language and French is the main one as i have English, BG and like 20 more columns with different languages and translations. So to sum it up, if there are no thick borders i will add them manually so it won't be any problem in the future.Also for the columns which are not Languages i will delete them(also, you ro?)

Comment: The gaps between the border ranges should be avoided. I mean if i have a thick border - empty line- thick line, it should be avoided and not taken into consideration and move to the next thick border

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230935/discussion-between-luca-and-faneduru).

Comment: So, the answer is **there are/may be gaps between the bordered ranges** and the columns to be processed should **not** be only the ones enumerated by you. If they will be consistently separated by n columns, they can be identified according to a specific algorithm. I can see in your picture three columns between French and English and only one between English and Bulgarian... The code can work if you supply an enumeration with the existing languages, **exactly** spelled. Comma delimited. Then, the processing should start from the third row. Is it correct? I only need you clarifying questions.

Comment: The Languages are: French, English, Bulgarian, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Estonian, Finnish, German, Hebrew, Hungarian, Italian, Latvian, Lithuanian, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Serbian, Slovakian, Slovenian, Spanish, Turkish, Ukrainian. I also did a trim of the excel file to make it easier to code it, hopefully and it doesn't matter if they are colored or not, same action should be taken for all of them. And yes, the processing should start from the third row and column B, i made a mistake and deleted the empty column A. 
https://imgur.com/a/hRc5J7a , col B third r

Comment: @FaneDuru
Please come here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66998146/how-to-flag-recipients-for-follow-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub testDetermineThickBorder()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, cel As Range, rngB As Range, lastR As Long, lastC As Long, strSep As String
 Dim iR As Long, jC As Long, arrC, El, nrRows As Long, i As Long, strCountries As String, rngDel As Range
 
 'put in an array the columns to be processed headers:
 strCountries = "French, English, Bulgarian, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Estonian, Finnish, German, Hebrew, Hungarian, Italian, Latvian, Lithuanian, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Serbian, Slovakian, Slovenian, Spanish, Turkish, Ukrainian"
 
 arrC = Split(strCountries, ", ")
 strSep = " " 'the separator between concatenated strings
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'you may use here your necessary sheet, if not the active one

 lastC = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column on the first row (the one with the headers to be checked)
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 
 For Each El In arrC     'iterate between the headers array elements
    For jC = 1 To lastC 'iterate between existing columns of the first row (headers)
        If UCase(sh.cells(1, jC).value) = UCase(El) Then      'if the header has been found
            lastR = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, jC).End(xlUp).row 'determine the last row on the specific column
            For iR = 3 To lastR                                        'iterate between all rows, starting from the third row
                If sh.cells(iR, jC).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium And sh.cells(iR, jC) <> "" Then
                    Set rngB = getBordRng(sh.cells(iR, jC))     'determine the range inside the border
                    If rngB Is Nothing Then GoTo OverProcessing 'in case of one row in the bordered area, the code jumps over the pocessing part
                    nrRows = rngB.rows.count                      'the range number of rows
                    For i = 1 To nrRows - 1                         'concatenate the range rows value to the first row
                       Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'to be faster, not allowing calculations for each change
                         sh.cells(iR, jC).value = sh.cells(iR, jC).value & strSep & sh.cells(iR + i, jC).value 'the concatenation
                         sh.cells(iR + i, jC).value = ""                    'clearing the cells below the above one
                            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                                Set rngDel = sh.cells(iR + i, jC)         'the range to be deleted is built
                            Else
                                'check if there already is a cell on the analized row:
                                If Intersect(rngDel.EntireRow, sh.cells(iR + i, jC)) Is Nothing Then
                                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.cells(iR + i, jC)) 'place the cell in the row to be deleted
                                End If
                            End If
                       Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                    Next i
                    iR = iR + nrRows - 1 'increment the variable to start after the previous determined range
                End If
OverProcessing:
            Next iR
        End If
    Next jC
 Next El
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function getBordRng(c As Range) As Range
   Dim iRow As Long, celBottom As Range, lastR As Long
    
    If c.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium Then
        Set getBordRng = Nothing: Exit Function 'for the case of only one row
    End If
    lastR = c.Parent.cells(rows.count, c.Column).End(xlUp).row 'last row
    For iRow = 1 To lastR
        If c.Offset(iRow, 0).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium Then
            Set getBordRng = c.Parent.Range(c, c.Offset(iRow, 0)): Exit Function
        End If
    Next iRow
End Function
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I copied the code ,ran it but nothing happens. For that           
Set sh = Worksheets("Translations") i put it like this with the name of my worksheet but nothing happens

Comment: @Luca: Does your sheet have the headers on the first row? If not something confidential, can you share it?

Comment: no, first row and column are empty. Take a look in here : https://imgur.com/a/NVznGm8

Comment: @Luca: I start feeling that I am wasting my time, sorry...  Look to your first picture and see on which row are the headers. Is it so difficult to simple delete the first row, in order to make your sheet looking like the one you posted and I used it like a model/sample?

Comment: Don't , i really appreciate all your time and hard work ^^. I am just trying to keep up and understand what you are doing. This is how it looks after i ran the macro https://imgur.com/a/wv0AG6x. Could you maybe add an empty space between the words and also delete the words so it looks like the second picture?

Comment: Of course, I can, but now I do not have a computer arround.. I did not make the code to clean tte rows before, on purpose. I wanted you to confirm that the code does what you can see. In a second step I will do it and also put the necessary code lines to make the code faster.

Comment: Damn, thank you so much ^^. Hope you are having a nice Sunday and it's not a rush as i am trying to figure things in parallel for this also, starting from what you wrote there and looking up for the syntaxes.

Comment: @Luca: Please, check the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: Wow, it does wonders now but i saw one problem which i think maybe it's my fault : https://imgur.com/a/DZrgAOG . As you can see, there are rows with only one cell with thick border. In rest i don't see anything else odd

Comment: @Luca: I cannot understand how you each time show us different pictures... But, I will adapt the code in one, two minutes...

Comment: @Luca: Please, test the updated code. It should skip the bordered ranges with only one row.

Comment: It does that, also i couldn't find any issues at all ( the files has ~ 1500 rows for each of that columns)

Comment: @Luca: I am not sure I understand what you mean... Does it work as you need, or it does not do anything?

Comment: Yes it is working like it should. Just the final step to merge the empty rows left from the concatenation.

Comment: @Luca: Do you want merging the empty rows below the concatenation one? If yes, this will make the code slower. Shouldn't it be better to simple delete them? This can be done by making a union and deleting them at once, at the end. Maybe, except one of them... Are there pieces of information on the other columns, not involved in processing? I could not see such fields in your last picture.

Comment: You are the expert here, if you know that deleting is better than merging i agree. And no, there are no leftovers (if i can say so) in any other columns, every info there is is being used in the process.

Comment: I am not an expert. I am even not a programmer... I only try making my life easier using some automations. So, should the code delete all rows which became empty (simpler), or all except one?

Comment: Delete all empty rows, but before that i want to tell you something that might be relevant. On column A the row ends at number 1300 and for the rest of them it ends at 1345, so it's a difference of 45 rows between the other columns. If the code deletes the empty rows can we make sure it won't delete this 45 rows from the other columns?

Comment: @Luca: It will not delete the other rows, but I am asking myself now: Couldn't it be possible to have different number of rows to be concatenated/deleted for all language columns?

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand your question. What you are asking is if we concatenate/delete each column individually? Because there are cases when a column has 4 rows and one has 2 or 3 at the same language translation. Ofc after the initial concatenation they all have one row but there is a difference between them for the empty rows if this makes sense on what i am trying to say

Comment: @Luca: Please, try the updated code. It will delete all rows which now become empty.

Comment: @Luca: Not exactly... The range containing cells to delete all their `EntireRow` is built during the code run. I was asking if is it possible to have different number of rows to be concatenated, per language column. Probably, not... It can be done in a different way, too. To determine which column has more rows, find its empty rows and delete all of them according to this reference column. This will also delete the initially existing empty rows.

Comment: As i am running the new script i've come across a weird error : so after it's done, all the empty rows are selected but when i press delete i get this : Cannot use that command on overlapping selections.

Comment: Also, maybe it's because some of the cells are colored? But i tried deleting them manually and it's working

Comment: @Luca: I forgot to tell you that I only let the code selecting the rows. Just in order to let you see if they are correctly selected. Theoretically, replacing `Select` with `Delete` it should do the job... It looks that having the range build by more cells **on the same row** does not allow the deletion. No time right now, but I will find a solution when I will not be so loaded... The coloring does not matter.

Comment: @Luca: Please, check the updated code. It now check if the row to be added to the range to be deleted already contains a cell and make the `Union` only if does not contain any cell. And I would like to remind you that, if the code works as you need, we here vote the answer up and more important, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the supplied solution works...

Comment: Yes it does, wonderful job and thanks. A virtual beer to you.

Comment: @Luca: Glad I could help! Now is your turn to learn something. I tried commenting the code in a way to be easily understood (I think...). When I will be in Timisoara I will try transforming it in a real one... :)

Comment: Great, i am always down for a beer :> . And yes, it really makes it easier to follow, maybe easier  for the ones using vba but for me at least now i can search on the internet the syntaxes you used and use them later if any other task like this occurs ( i hope not) :).

Comment: @Luca: It is good to learn VBA not only for such a future task, I think. It is easy to be learned and you will be able to create a task for yourself when you will have **a need**. It may save hours of (manual) work...